# Microcontroller PWM output volume

Tags: microcontroller, audio, analog, pwm, volume

So I am designing a cheap and simple sound device using the Atmega32U4 uC and stumbled across one problem.

I am using the 10-bit PWM output of the uC to output audio and I want the user to be able to control the output volume using buttons, not a discrete potentiometer. A typical solution would be to just decrease the PWM output duty; but that way I am losing the already low resolution - by decreasing the output volume only by 10dB I already get 60% lower output voltage, and, therefore, I am entering the 8-bit resolution territory already.

That's why I started looking for a cheap hardware volume decreasing solution and I don't want to use a digital potentiometer, since they are relatively pricey. In the end, I came up with the solution shown below; basically, it uses two uC PWM outputs, one to control the volume (VOLPWM) and one to output the audio (OUTPWM); the VOLPWM gets heavily integrated and then the Q1 switches according to the OUTPWM between ground and the VOLPWM output voltage. Notice that the output integration happens **after** the Q1+R2 pair, pure PWM signal enters the Q1 base.

I've also considered using a push-pull pair instead of Q1+R2, however, I wasn't able to get a decent low level output.

My questions are:

1. Are there any better solutions to my problem?
2. Won't the similar value of R2 and R5 be problematic?
3. What could be the other cons of my solution?

[image: Dual PWM solution]

Comment: Do you have anything to limit base current in Q1?

Comment: @Colin nope, but you're right, maybe adding a series 1k resistor would be better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's actually pretty good — you've created a multiplying DAC.

The biggest problem I see is that the integrator time constant varies with whether Q1 is on or off — when it's on, you have only R5 in the circuit, but when it's off, you have R2 + R5 in series. To minimize the effect of this, make R5 a couple of orders of magnitude larger than R2. (Reduce the value of C2 to compensate.)

Comment: Any other ways to reduce the R2-R5 effect? If I will increase R5, I'll have to decrease the C2 accordingly and I am not sure how the integrator will operate with a several pF capacitor in it's feedback and with the low currents that the R5 will produce.

Comment: Thanks, by the way, for saying that it is called a multiplying DAC, I'll look into it.

Comment: @sx107 I know this is an old thread, but wondering if you went any further with this and if so what component values you settled on?

Comment: @IanBland Worked perfectly. The values on the schematic are more or less the same as I've settled on, though I think I've replaced the output integrator with a follower and a rc filter.

Comment: Interesting, thanks!